# use QThread exclusively for an object

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread, qt4.8

**EDIT2**

Here is the solution that works for the following problem of giving a QThread exclusively to the object.

I've changed the approach for the problem. I don't want to close QThread in MyClass anymore, cause the following solution seems easier and not too bad looking.

My solution is modification of the solution given here: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

The problem with that solution was that QObject worker wasn't really deleted (checked it).

```
QThread *myThread = new QThread();
SCIntermediary* myObj = new MyClass();
myObj->moveToThread(myThread);
connect(myThread, SIGNAL(started()), myObj, SLOT(setup()));
connect(myObj, SIGNAL(destroyed()), myThread, SLOT(quit()), Qt::DirectConnection);
connect(myObj, SIGNAL(finished()), myObj, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(myThread, SIGNAL(finished()), myThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
myThread -> start();

// do your work bla bla bla

myObj -> finishIt(); // this function only emits finish() signal of myObj
myThread -> wait();
```

This is the first solution that worked for me destroying both myObj and myThread without any errors or other troubles at all.

**ENDOF EDIT**

I'm trying to create a class will do some stuff between my client and my server. I'd like it to have it's own thread. So what I did is:

```
class Myclass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Myclass();
    ~Myclass();

private:
    QThread *my_thread;
    QTcpSocket *sock;
}
```

Here is how I coded my constructor:

```
Myclass::Myclass(){
    my_thread = new QThread();
    my_thread -> start();
    moveToThread(my_thread);

    sock = new QTcpSocket(this);
    sock -> connectToHost("host", port);
}
```

This didn't work. It didn't work, because the code for TcpSocket wasn't executed in the same thread the parent object currently is. So what I decided to do is to create slot and signal for setup and emit it in my constructor. Here is how my code looks right now.

```
class Myclass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Myclass();
    ~Myclass();

public slots:
    void setup();

signals:
    void do_setup();

private:
    QThread *my_thread;
    QTcpSocket *sock;
}
```

And some of it's implementation

```
Myclass::Myclass(){
    my_thread = new QThread();
    my_thread -> start();
    moveToThread(my_thread);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(do_setup()), this, SLOT(setup()));
    emit do_setup();
}

void Myclass::setup(){
    sock = new QTcpSocket();
    sock -> connectToHost("host", port);
}
```

Now it works and here comes the sad part - it looks terrible! It's awful and I have no idea how to make it look better or how such pattern should be done in the first place. What would you advice me to do to get the same effect?

Additionally - I have no idea how to write good destructor for this - how to delete QThread smoothly and all the class objects..

**EDIT**

For now I believe the solution is quite alright - the only problem left is how to write a destructor for that. I have no idea how it can be done here.

Comment: Why not inherit MyClass  from QThread instead of inheriting from QObject? Then my class wiil not have private QThread member at all. This way your QTcpSocket will be located in required thread if it has MyClass as a parent, also makes destructor clearer as QThread will be deleted last...

Comment: Also, in current design you can use QTimer::singleShot() with zero time instead of adding do_setup signal to keep MyClass less busy...

Comment: Yeah I agree with QTimer::singleShot() instead of signals, but it looks like hacking as well... I was once told not to inherit QThread because it's bad design. So I'm looking for other options

Comment: Yes  inherit QThread is no longer recommended, see the Qt documentation

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you play with where you put moveToThread(my_thread);, in your original example, would it change anything? say, if you put that statement as last line of your constructor - so you move object with all its children to new thread once it is fully constructed? or, just before connecting socket but after creating it?

Comment: If it's after everything then of course - it works, but after creating before connecting surprisingly throws error that it's not in proper thread...

Comment: Correction... I must have done something wrong earlier - it works without error, but connection to socket is done on the same thread the whole constructor is working on. I want to avoid such behavior

Comment: If original example works fine when putting moveToThread(my_thread); to the end of constructor, why not use that construction?

Comment: I don't want to construct socket and connect to the server in the same thread I'm creating it's. It blocks my main thread

Comment: @benjarobin, yes, I've heard it is not recommended, however all official documentation that I can google still say to inherit it - for example, http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qthread.html Can you please provide link to updated Qt docs?

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html : "Detailed Description" and "Notes (bottom of the page)"

Comment: I think now the best option is not to put QThread in MyClass... It looks like there are too many things to worry about when we want to clean up :)

Comment: For destructor, check out Maya Posch example - http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/ Since your thread is not child of MyClass, perhaps you can finish thread as lst thing in destructor and connect finished signal to deleteLater for thread?

Comment: There are examples of how to properly do this without subclassing a QThread. You are supposed to wire your custom slots to the signals emitted by the thread when it starts and stops.... THEN you start the thread. The signals emitted by the thread will call the slots and still be in that thread. Dont do anything else with the object from that main thread.

Comment: That's very useful, thank you Ilya, I'd accept it as answer to the whole topic so don't hesitate to post it

Comment: jdi - thanks that's another thing I'll need.

Comment: @Gricha, I added the answer, I edited it a bit to make it more clear if anyone reads it, but I guess you already got all the information you needed from the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For destructor, check out Maya Posch example:
http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/ 
Since your thread is not child of MyClass, perhaps you can call finish() on thread as last thing in destructor and connect destroyed() signal of MyClass to deleteLater for thread?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I do now - only one correction - you need to make that connection as DirectConnection to call it on the thread you are closing (actually it calls quit, and finished on thread calls it's deleteLater).

Comment: @Gricha The `Qt::DirectConnection` between `myObj->destroyed()` and `myThread->quit()` is only allowed because `quit()` is thread-safe. You're directly calling a function of myThread from a thread other than `myThread->thread()` which generally isn't safe.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a signal, you could use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "setup", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

But this is still heavy, but I guess this is the better option... If anyone have better idea, comment :-)

Comment: I like it - it takes of the signal hack. I agree it is still not the solution but we're closer to it ;) thanks

Answer (score -1):

What about this, I think manually moving socket to newly created thread right before connecting it should work, since both objects should be in the same thread which is newly created one?

```
Myclass::Myclass()
{
    my_thread = new QThread();
    my_thread -> start();
    moveToThread(my_thread);

    sock = new QTcpSocket(this);
    sock -> moveToThread(my_thread);
    sock -> connectToHost("host", port);
}
```

Comment: It won't work. Let's say you are in thread A now. You are moving this object to thread B. But the method is still in thread A. So you are trying to create a socket in thread A, and as parent you give it something that belongs to thread B. You cannot do that. The error you'll get is: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.